# toggle form/unit view (F12 key) in RAD studio 2010

Tags: forms, delphi, view, ide, toggle

Is there a way to fix view->toggle form/unit feature in RAD 2010? In good old borland pascals, F12 used to send the form back, behind the code. When i press F12 with a form visible in RAD studio 2010, it just changes appearance, like it's "always on top" within IDE. I can't see the code then, and have to close the form using its close button.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have changed the IDE setting `Tools` - `Options` - `Environment Options` - `VCL Designer` - `Embedded Designer` to be `False`. Probably to be able to see both the designer and code at the same time. In this state the designer view stays in front of the IDE and the <kbd>F12</kbd> only toggles focus between the designer form and the IDE.

You don't really have to close the Designer view, you can also just minimize it.

If you revert the above setting (to enable `Embedded Designer`) the switch between Designer view and Code view happens as you wish with <kbd>F12</kbd>, but you will not be able to see both simultaneously.

Another option is to keep the present disabled `Embedded Designer` setting and open up a new edit view, with menu item `View` - `New Edit view`. In this case <kbd>F12</kbd> toggles between the secondary code view and the form designer and also brings the focused window into front.

Thanks to @dummzeuch, there's also the possibility to change to "Classic undocked" desktop layout. You can change the desktop layout either by menu "View" - "Desktops" or by the dropdown in the toolbar.

Comment: It also works fine if he switches his desktop layout to "Classic undocked". Only the combination of a docked desktop and non-embedded designer creates this effect.

Comment: "Classic undocked" - that's my desired behavior. Thank you.

Comment: This is still valid for Tokyo 10.2 Release 1 and the particular setting that is set when using "Classic undocked" can be found in the View menu and is named "Dock edit window".

Comment: You've saved my day. Great tip!